# Electron bulder Unhandled rejection HttpError: 404 Not Found on private repo

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am using [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) as a private repo. My development app is working fine.

When I try `yarn package --mac`  installer is getting created but app is giving me error

```
Unhandled rejection HttpError: 404 Not Found
"method: undefined url: https://github.com/myuser/thisapp/releases.atom\n\nPlease double check that your authentication token is correct. Due to security reasons actual status maybe not reported, but 404.\n"
```

My [logs and package](https://gist.github.com/niksmac/80d21cc306a3b4c1c8ffbb2da04349ff)